# Show that exactly one of the following two systems has a solution.

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, linear-programming

> Let A be a $m \times n$ matrix, $\mathbf{c}$ an $n$-dimensional ector and $\mathbf{b} \ge \mathbf{0}$ an $m$-dimensional vector. Show that exactly one of the following two systems has a solution:
>   $\begin{align*}
> 1. \ Ax \le z, \mathbf{c}^tx \gt \mathbf{d}^tz, x \ge \mathbf{0}, z \le \mathbf{0}, x \in \mathbb{R}^n, z\in \mathbb{R}^m 
> \end{align*}$
>   $\begin{align*}
> 2. \ A^t y \ge c \, , y\ge \mathbf{d} \, , y\in \mathbb{R}^m
> \end{align*}$
>   I usually put here what I've done so far, but in this case I only know what I should do instead of some concrete calculations.

That statement above looks pretty similar to [Farka's lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma), and I've seen some corollaries that are consequences of Farka's lemma whose proofs consist in some modifications on the matrix of the formulation of Faka's lemma. However, I don't know how I should modify the matrix so the exercise follows. Any help will be highly appreciate and thanks in advance!

By the way, I don't know if the tags are accurate so feel free to edit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite (2) as $By \leq a$, where
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
-A^t \\ -I
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ and }
a = \begin{bmatrix}
-c \\ -d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132462/understanding-a-proof-of-corollary-of-farkas-lemma), this system has a solution if and only if $y \geq 0, y^t B = 0, y^t a < 0$ has no solution $y$. So now, we just need to show that this system is equivalent to (1).

If we let $y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}$ and expand the definition of $A$ and $b$, then the system looks like this:

$$
y_1 \geq 0, y_2 \geq 0, \qquad
y_1^t (-A^t) + y_2^t (-I) = 0, \qquad
y_1^t (-c) + y_2^t (-d) < 0
$$

We can simplify this to:
$$
y_1, y_2 \geq 0, \qquad
A y_1 + y_2 = 0, \qquad
c^t y_1 + d^t y_2 > 0
$$
Now, if we replace $y_1$ by $x$ and $y_2$ by $-z$, we get (1)!

Comment: You are completely right! It should be $z \le 0$. I've changed that already. Thank you very much!

Comment: That's encouraging to hear! I'll edit out my remark